# Python - Group_by custom function doesnt works for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
def agg_count(df, group_field):
    grouped = df.groupby(group_field, as_index=False).size()
    #grouped.sort(ascending = False)

    grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped).reset_index()
    grouped.columns = [group_field, 'Count']
    return grouped
```

Above function, works fine if I call it with one column as below :

```
agg_count(app_snap1_extract, 'APP_STATUS_C')
```

It fails if I call the function with multiple columns (I wanted to customize the function such that i can group by N no of columns provided as arguments)

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

When passing multiple columns for `groupby` in pandas, you need to pass it as a `list`.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['a','b'])
```

So, make sure `group_field` is a list like above. That will work.

### Just change your function like this:

```
def agg_count(df, group_field):
    grouped = df.groupby(group_field, as_index=False).size()
    #grouped.sort(ascending = False)

    grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped).reset_index()
    grouped.columns = group_field + ['Count']
    return grouped
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, can you kindly help in changing the function ? i am not able to do it.

Comment: You don't need to change the function at all. Just pass `group_field` like a list when you call your function. Something like this: `agg_count(app_snap1_extract, ['APP_STATUS_C', 'APP_STATUS_B'])`

Comment: i tried it that way it doesnt works.ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 2 elements